# Pick an image and resize to 72x72

Tags: android, bitmap

I picked an image from gallery and decoded it. Now I just want to resize that bitmap to standard 72x72 size in order to use as an profile photo.

I searched a lot but nothing worked, some of them rotated my image for no reason, some of them makes image very low quality. Is it that hard?

**EDIT**

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode)
    { 
    case 100:   // SELECT_PHOTO
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream;
            try
            {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            }catch (Exception e){ return; }

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 72, 72, true);
            UpdateAvatar(bm);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Not useful. Check scaled 72x72 and original one:

72x72 (As you see, rotated and very bad quality)
http://imgim.com/9958incic3494599.png

original:
http://imgim.com/3847incix7666386.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Or other way-

```
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

Comment: Edited my post. It makes the image very bad.

Comment: please see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465686/android-resizing-bitmaps-without-losing-quality

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not that hard. Just use [`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29):

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
```

Comment: rotating 90degree and making very very bad quality images taken with Galaxy S4.

Comment: @MelihAkln It doesn't rotate an image. You can check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#Bitmap.createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%2Cint%2Cint%2Cboolean%29). What do you mean by very bad quality images? Can you post an original and scaled image? It should just scale an image to 72x72. Maybe there is a bug in some other part of your code. You can post your full code too, it can be helpful.

Comment: Edited my post. Check it please. There's a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a method that would give me a maximum of 120x120 image, hope this helps you :

```
public static Bitmap decodeWithBounds(String srcImg) {

    Bitmap image;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(srcImg, options);


    if (options.outHeight > 120 || options.outWidth > 120) {

        options.inSampleSize = Math.max(
                Math.round(options.outHeight / 120),
                Math.round(options.outWidth / 120));
    }
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(srcImg, options);
    return image;

}
```